# Is there an efficent method similar to sql window functions in PySpark?

Tags: performance, pyspark, bigdata, apache-spark-sql

I am dealing with a huge dataframe containing 3 columns and 5 Bil. rows. The size of the data is 360 GB. For the analysis of the Data I am using the following set-up:

-Jupyternotebooks running on a AWS r4.16xlarge

-PySpark Kernel

The table called `customer_sales` looks similar to the following example:

```
    +--------------------+----------+-------+
    |  business_unit_id  | customer | sales |
    +--------------------+----------+-------+
    |                  1 +        a +  5000 +
    |                  1 +        b +  2000 +
    |                  1 +        c +  3000 +
    |                  1 +        d +  5000 +
    |                  2 +        f +   600 +
    |                  2 +        c +  7000 +
    |                  3 +        j +   200 +
    |                  3 +        k +   800 +
    |                  3 +        c +  4500 +
```

Now I want to get for each `business_unit_id` the `customer` with the highest `sales`. If there is a draw in `sales` between several `customer` I want to get them all. The information should be stored in a table called `best_customers_for_each_unit`. So for the above illustrated example the table `best_customers_for_each_unit` looks as follows:

```
    +--------------------+----------+-------+
    |  business_unit_id  | customer | sales |
    +--------------------+----------+-------+
    |                  1 +        a +  5000 +
    |                  1 +        d +  5000 +
    |                  2 +        c +  7000 +
    |                  3 +        c +  4500 +
```

In a second step I want to count how often it happens that a `customer` is the one with the highest `sales` in a specific `business_unit_id`. The output of this query will be:

```
    +----------+-------+
    | customer | count |
    +----------+-------+
    |        a +     1 +
    |        b +     1 +
    |        c +     2 +
```

For the first query I used spark.sql with window functions. The used query looks as follows:

```
     best_customers_for_each_unit = spark.sql("""
     SELECT 
          business_unit_id,
          customer,
          sales
     FROM (
          SELECT
             business_unit_id,
             customer,
             sales,
             dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY business_unit_id ORDER BY sales DESC)as rank
          FROM customer_sales) tmp
     WHERE
     rank =1
     """)
```

For the second query I used the following PySpark snipped:

```
     best_customers_for_each_unit.groupBy("customer").count()
```

My queries do actually work, but it takes ages to only process a minor part of the data. So do you know any efficient way to do such queries with PySpark?

Regards

Comment: Can you post the execution plan? This should be quite fast if the business_unit_id contains a lot of unique values.

Comment: How many partitions are you using ? Repartitioning into a larger number of partitions might help

Comment: @FokkoDriesprong what do you mean by execution plan? Do you mean the output of the function `explain()`?